# Handling WCF Rest Service exceptions only in one place

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm developing an WCF Rest service that I'm going to host on an IIS.

Now I'm implementing Service Contract, and I see that I'm repeating the same code on all of my methods when I'm trying to handle exceptions.

This is one of my Service Contract method:

```
public void DeleteMessage(string message_id)
{
    int messageId;
    OutgoingWebResponseContext ctx =
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

    if ((message_id == null) || (!Int32.TryParse(message_id, out messageId)) || (messageId < 1))
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        ctx.StatusDescription = "message_id parameter is not valid";
        throw new ArgumentException("DeleteMessage: message_id is not valid", "message_id");
    }

    try
    {
        using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
        {
            Message message = new Message() { MessageId = messageId };

            context.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();

            ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        ctx.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    }
}
```

On all of my methods I could throw an `ArgumentException` or an `Exception`, and manage them with return a `HTTP STATUS CODE`.

**Is there any way to catch that exceptions globally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MS-recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513227.aspx) approach appears to follow [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx) pattern. The idea is to implement [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426351/how-to-setup-up-web-config-for-wcf-ierrorhandler) explains how to set it up in WCF configuration.

Having seen an implementation of this pattern in old-style WCF service I can tell that it probably makes sense only for complex enterprise-level scenarios. For simple cases I'd stick with throwing exceptions manually.

Another alternative is to implement REST service with [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It has nice exception handling [strategy](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) out of the box and that's what Microsoft is actually recommends for REST development in [.NET Technology Guide for Business Applications](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832707).

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer but I don't a complex enterprise-level scenario. I only want to not repeat code. Thanks.

Comment: Well, in short, there is no good simple alternative for throwing exceptions mostly because WCF is not very HTTP-friendly in the first place. I'd do the whole thing in Web API instead, took me two days to figure it out completely from the scratch - way less  boilerplate with MVC code conventions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wcf-rest-tip-2 Sorry, I haven't explained well.

Answer (score 0):

WCF has an excellent built-in extensibility mechanism for converting exceptions to faults. This extensibility point can be consumed through the IErrorHandler interface, which provides two methods: HandleError and ProvideFault. The HandleError method is called on a separate thread after the call has already completed, to possibly log the error and perform other operations. Below is a useful link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault.aspx

LoggingConfiguration Section in service web.config file is another option to log errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa303433.aspx